# Moving file to Recycle Bin

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to move file to recycle bin using shutil library. Following is relevant code lines, but I get kinda strange error. Both files are local, and I can access both locations on my PC. Why this error occurs? Because I run Main.py it from F:?

```
import shutil
# Path to folder where files should be trashed
dump_folder = r"C:\$Recycle.Bin\\"
file_name = "C:\\Storage\\\\statuti.docx"

# Move it to storage directory
shutil.move(file_name, dump_folder)
```

Error message

F:\Python\Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 54648 --file F:\Python\Main.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.5981.165)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 788, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Storage\\statuti.docx' -> 'C:\Recycle.Bin\\'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Recycle.Bin\\'

Comment: Use the Send2Trash module - https://pypi.org/project/Send2Trash/

Comment: Are you targetting only windows?

Comment: there is a two backslash in dumpfolder path. i did not check but that looks like an issue. 'C:\Recycle.Bin\\'

Comment: Yes, targeting Windows only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To send something to the recycle bin it is much easier to use `send2trash`. It is cross platform and very easy to use.

You can install it with :

```
pip install Send2Trash
```

Then you can use it :

```
from send2trash import send2trash
send2trash(filename)
```

Comment: Nope, it does not work. file_name = "C:\\Storage\\\\statuti.docx", send2trash(filename). File stays in its location, nothing in recycle bin. And no error messages. Debug returns -1, run returns 0.

Comment: The problem is related with the quadruple backslash. You should use `"C:\\Storage\\statuti.docx"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for help, I accept your answer. For any dummy in future I leave some lines str_fn = filename, str_fn = str_fn.replace("\\\\", "\\"), send2trash(str_fn)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Windows 10 and `send2trash` is only accepting path with backslash `\`. It throws `OSError: [WinError xxxxxxxxxx] The parameter is incorrect` when you tried to pass a directory with forward slash `/`.

This code should replace the `/` with `\`, and fix the error:

```
path_to_delete = path_to_delete.replace("/", "\\")
send2trash(path_to_delete)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you install the Send2Trash module, which works across platforms. You can get it from PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/Send2Trash/